# navbar affix shows no effect on navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a this navbar and i'm trying to make it affix after 100px scroll down, I've tried many tutorials for this but looks like it has no effect on my code.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

```js
 $('#nav').affix({
   offset: {
     top: 100
   }
 });
```

```css
#nav {
  margin: 0;
}
#nav.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" id="nav" class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="position: relative; z-index:0; ">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    </button>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-left inpage-links">
    <li class="find-agent-btn"><a href="#" class="fa fa-search-plus"> Find Agents <span class="caret"></span></a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right inpage-links">
    <li>
      <a href="#home" class="fa fa-home"></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#browse" class="fa fa-road"> Browse Property</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#map" class="fa fa-map-marker"> Maps</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="fa fa-book"> About</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="fa fa-phone "> Contact</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
</div>
```

I've seen a lots of other questions on stack overflow about this and tried almost everyone of their answer, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: 1st your snippet needs jQuery and Bootstrap Libraries to work. 2nd, if you scroll with devTools open you will that changes from `affix-top` to `affix` so my guess is it would be some CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the inline style

```
style="position: relative; z-index:0; "
```

from #nav

I think the position:relative is overriding the positioning you are trying to do with the .affix class.